# Is it possible query if a single RingCentral user has Automatic Call Recording (ACR) enabled?

Tags: ringcentral, call-recording

Are there any APIs that we can query if current extension is added into auto recording list?

We have a web phone using the stop/start recording Call Control API but it doesn't work when auto recording is enabled, so in our app, we need to disable the recording button. We need a way to identify if a user has ACR enabled without retrieving all the users.

We can get extension list with the following account-wide API, but it doesn't take any query parameters to filter the results. If we check this way, we need to load all extensions which takes too long.

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Rule-Management/listCallRecordingExtensions

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/call-recording/extensions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information on whether an individual user has Automatic Call Recording (ACR) enabled is available in the extension endpoint and is separately controlled for inbound and outbound calls.

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}
```

The extension response includes a `serviceFeatures` features property which is an array of features. Filter this property for a feature matching the following:

- `featureName` IN (`AutomaticInboundCallRecording`, `AutomaticOutboundCallRecording`)
- `enabled` = true

Here's an example response showing only the `serviceFeatures` property value for those two features:

```json
{
  "serviceFeatures": [
    {
      "featureName": "AutomaticInboundCallRecording",
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "featureName": "AutomaticOutboundCallRecording",
      "enabled": false,
      "reason": "ExtensionLimitation"
    }
  ]
}
```

See more here:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/User-Settings/readExtension